# Assigment and adding operator overloading (concatenation of 2 tables and int)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm trying to concatenate two arrays and at the end concatenate *int*, for example: result = arg + arg + 2;
I'm getting "read access violation" at + operator overloading.
I wrote the error and warning in comments below.

My code:

Main:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CTable.h"
int main() {

    CTable c_tab1, c_tab0;
    c_tab0.SetNewSize(3);
    c_tab1.SetNewSize(2);

    c_tab0.SetValueAt(0, 22);
    c_tab0.SetValueAt(1, 23);
    c_tab0.SetValueAt(2, 24);
    c_tab0.Print();

    c_tab1.SetValueAt(0, 31);
    c_tab1.SetValueAt(1, 32);
    c_tab1.Print();

    CTable c_tab3 = (c_tab0 + c_tab1 + 111);
    c_tab3.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Class CTable:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class CTable {

public:
    CTable();
    CTable(string sName, int iTableLen);
    CTable(const CTable& pcOther);
    CTable* pcClone();
    ~CTable();

    void ShowName();
    void ShowSize();
    void SetName(string sName);
    bool SetNewSize(int iTableLen);
    void SetValueAt(int iOffset, int iNewVal);
    void Print();
    CTable& operator+(const CTable& pcNewTable);
    CTable operator+(int iNewVal) const;
    CTable& operator=(const CTable& pcNewVal) {
        if (this != &pcNewVal) {
        for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++) {
            this->piTable[i] = pcNewVal.piTable[i];
        }
    }
        return *this;
    }

private:
    string s_name;
    int i_size;
    int* piTable;

    const int SIZE = 10;
    const string NAME = "Name";
};
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "CTable.h"
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

CTable::CTable() {
    s_name = NAME;
    cout << "bezp: " << s_name << endl;
    piTable = new int[SIZE];
    i_size = SIZE;
}

CTable::CTable(string sName, int iTableLen) {
    s_name = sName;
    cout << "parametr: " << sName << endl;
    piTable = new int[iTableLen];
    i_size = iTableLen;
}

CTable::CTable(const CTable& pcOther) {
    s_name = pcOther.s_name + "copied";
    piTable = new int[pcOther.i_size];
    i_size = pcOther.i_size;
    for (int i = 0; i < pcOther.i_size; i++) { 
        piTable[i] = pcOther.piTable[i];
    }
}

CTable::~CTable() {
    delete[] piTable;
}

void CTable::SetName(string sName) {

    s_name = sName;
}

bool CTable::SetNewSize(int iTableLen) {

    if (iTableLen <= 0) {
        cout << "Length has to be greater than 0" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    int* pi_newTable = new int[iTableLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < iTableLen; i++) {
        pi_newTable[i] = piTable[i];
    }
    delete this->piTable;
    this->i_size = iTableLen;
    this->piTable = pi_newTable;

    return true;
}

CTable* CTable::pcClone() {
    CTable* ct = new CTable(s_name, i_size); 
    return ct;
}

void CTable::ShowName() {
    cout << "Name: " << s_name << endl;
}

void CTable::ShowSize() {
    cout << "Size: " << i_size << endl;
}

void CTable::SetValueAt(int iOffset, int iNewVal) {
    if (iOffset >= this->i_size) {
        return;
    }
    piTable[iOffset] = iNewVal;
}

void CTable::Print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++) {
        cout << piTable[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

CTable& CTable::operator+(const CTable& pcNewTable) {
    CTable result("new_int", this->i_size);

    result.i_size = (i_size + pcNewTable.i_size);
    result.piTable = new int[i_size + pcNewTable.i_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++) {
        result.piTable[i] = piTable[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (pcNewTable.i_size); i++) {
        result.piTable[i+i_size] = pcNewTable.piTable[i];
    }
    return result; //Warning C4172 returning address of local variable or temporary: result
}

CTable CTable::operator+(int iNewVal) const {
    CTable result("new_int", this->i_size);
    result.i_size = (i_size + 1);
    result.piTable = new int[i_size + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++) {
        result.piTable[i] = piTable[i]; //Exception thrown: read access violation. **this->piTable** was 0x1110122.
    }
    result.piTable[i_size + 1] = iNewVal;
    return result;
}
```

What should I correct? I'm not sure about assigment operator overload, is it okay?

Comment: That's a lot of code, please check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can better help you.

Comment: Don't ignore the warning.

Comment: In the `operator+(const CTable&)` function `result` is a local variable whose life will end when the function return. You can't return a reference to it. I recommend you take a look at [this canonical implementations reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Canonical_implementations) for help about how to overload operators. And you have the correct return-type for `operator+(int)`, why not for the other function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member function SetNewSize has undefined behavior. In this loop

```
int* pi_newTable = new int[iTableLen];
for (int i = 0; i < iTableLen; i++) {
    pi_newTable[i] = piTable[i];
}
```

it 1) uses uninitialized values because the array was not initialized and 2) `iTableLen` can be gretaer than the current value of `i_size`. You should at least zero initialize the array in constructors.

The copy assignment operator aslo has undefined behabior because the number of elements of the array of the object `pcNewVal` can be less than the number of elements of the array in the assigned object.

The first overloaded `operator +` also have undefined behavior. For starters as the warning says the operator returns reference to the local object result that will not be alive after exiting the operator. Secondly, there is a memory leak necause the array of the object is allocated anew and the previuous allocated memory in the constructor is not freed.

```
CTable result("new_int", this->i_size);

result.i_size = (i_size + pcNewTable.i_size);
result.piTable = new int[i_size + pcNewTable.i_size];
//...
```

The second overloaded `operator +` also has undefined behavior. As in the previous operator there is a memory leak.

In this statement

```
result.piTable[i_size + 1] = iNewVal;
```

there is an access memory outside the allocated array. There should be

```
result.piTable[i_size] = iNewVal;
```

Comment: Okay, understood. So basicly the code in those operators should have been similar to the code in `SetNewSize`.